# How to see the function definition of a function pointer in Ghidra

Tags: ghidra, pointer

i was wondering how to get to the function definition of a function pointer. Currently i have a function which is called in the following way:

```
iVar = (*DAT)(param_2, PTR_s)
```

When i press on *DAT i see that it is referenced by several functions. What i am wondering know is what the function definition looks like because i am interested in what the function is doing. How do i get to the function definition from the pointer?

Comment: Is `DAT` a global variable?

Comment: Ehhh, i am quite new to ghidra. How can i see if this is the case?

Comment: @Hakan hi and welcome to RE.SE. Are you new to C also? You seem to be confused about the syntax here also.

Answer (score -1):

Did you find this code in the decompile windows of Ghidra, right? 
In my case, it can be like this format: `DAT_00000a30`.
So if you go to the address 00000a30 in the Assemble windows (press G, and input 0a30), you can find the `DAT_00000a30` part.